# Redirect to OAuth url google+

Tags: php, html, google-plus

I have created two files that I run using xampp on localhost.

The first file is my .php file that acts as a server as describe in the google+ api docs for server side authentication:

```
<?php   
    set_include_path("Google" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Auth/OAuth2.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';
    require_once 'Google/Http/Request.php';


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId("...");
    $client->setClientSecret("...");
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setApplicationName('app');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('...');
    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');


    session_start();
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
        die;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: ".$authUrl);
        die;
    }

    echo 'Successful';
?>
```

In the above, it is supposed to "redirect" the client to `$authUrl` if no accessToken exists. However, it does NOT redirect them at all. If I echo a link with the url & click it, then it works just fine.

My HTML page looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            (function() {
                var po = document.createElement('script');
                po.type = 'text/javascript';
                po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id='signInBtn' class="g-signin"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            data-clientid="...."
            data-callback="onSignInCallback"
            data-theme="dark"
            data-redirecturi="postmessage"
            data-accesstype="offline"
            data-approvalprompt="auto"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-width="wide">
        </button>

        <div id="response" class="hide">
            <p id="responseContainer" style="width:100%; height:150px"></p>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSignInCallback(authResult) {
            if (authResult['code']) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'storeToken.php',
                    data: {code : authResult['code']},
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Did I do something wrong? Why does it not redirect them to the url so they can "accept"?

Comment: echo `$client->getAccessToken()` separately and see what is the result

Comment: Nothing. It's null/non-existent so it is entering the if statement

Comment: instead of die, try using exit(). Both are equivalent, but I have heard ppl discourage die()

Comment: I think you also need to add a call to `if($client->getAccessToken()) { $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); }`. But definitely get rid of the 'die()' statement.

Comment: I did all of the above, none of it worked. Changed die to exit. Added that if statement, etc.